# Unused let expression in Ocaml

Tags: compiler-errors, ocaml, unused-variables, unused-functions

Why can't I compile a program with unused variables in Ocaml?

`let foo a b = a + b`

--
Error (warning 32 [unused-value-declaration]): unused value foo.

Comment: You can. By default ocaml does not treat warnings as errors. You're using something else that enables this option. Probably `dune`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can disable the promotion of the warning to an error by customizing the flags in your dune file:

```
 (flags (:standard -warn-error "-unused-value-declaration"))
```

or disabling the promotion with an attribute in the file itself

```
[@@@warnerror "-unused-value-declaration"]
```

or for just the value:

```
let[@warnerror "-unused-value-declaration"] x = ()
```

(and you can use `-w` and `@warning` for disabling the warning itself rather than its promotion to an error.)

It is also possible to use a leading underscore to indicate the intent that a value is purposefully unused:

```
let _x = ()
```

Nevertheless, I find this warning generally useful to avoid dead code in the source code and I would not recommend to disable it.